How to access values in application.properties defined in another file in Spring Boot
I want to outsource my Database Connection and credentials from application.properties and access them in my application.properties.
I created a file called env.properties.
DB_USER=test
DB_PASSWORD=test
DB_URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testDB

Then imported the file into my application.properties and tried to access the values.
spring.application.name=CampusFlow
spring.config.import=optional:env.properties
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

spring.datasource.url=Environment#getProperty("DB_URL")
spring.datasource.username=Environment#getProperty("DB_USER")
spring.datasource.password=Environment#getProperty("DB_PASSWORD")

Like this, I was not able to access the value of my variables. How would I access the values?

Why don't you just add a properties file for dedicated environments containing the required data, eg application-production.properties? This way you have all the relevant data bundled and also have a config file associated with its profile.

I was trying to hide my credentials and connection and found this convenient solution but wasn't able to get what I was aiming for.  To be honest application-production.properties wasn't even in my scope. Thanks for the comment, I'll try it this way.

You have to use ${} notation.
Example that worked for me:
application.yml
spring:
 config:
  import:
   env.properties
myvar: ${TEST}

env.properties
TEST=myvar


Like this I could access my values, thanks. Nevertheless I should rename my evn.properties into application-dev.properties.

Excellent question. The easiest way is to just replace them like this:
spring.application.name=CampusFlow
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

spring.datasource.url=${DB_URL}
spring.datasource.username=${DB_USER}
spring.datasource.password=${DB_PASSWORD}

However this will not take it from env.properties, but the from the environment variables. Actually it will take it from 15 places, in this specific order: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config
Moreover, the spring.config.import property is for Spring Cloud config server, which can exactly do what you imagined to do, however this requires another application to be maintained / hosted / etc. So I'd rather not recommend it.
What can be recommended as an easy alternative is if you want to anyways "inject" them from a file, is to use the SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON (either as environment variable, or jvm argument, or spring property) and put the content in JSON format, something like this:
{
    "DB_USER": "test",
    "DB_PASSWORD": "test",
    "DB_URL": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testDB"
}

However, in any meaningful environment you can get variables injected to the container / runtime in a secure way and most likely you will not have to do this partial file configuration, just use the placeholder configurations as mentioned above with injected values.
